# Working with arrays - clone

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I have an array:

```
$obj = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
        )
);
```

How can I based on the **qty** can convert the array to this:

```
$obj2 = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
        )
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well normally people what to do it the other way. But where is the problem at doing it?

Comment: use a for loop based on the qty,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$obj = array(
    0 => (object) array(
        'id' => 1,
        'qty' => 2
    ),
    1 => (object) array(
        'id' => 2,
        'qty' => 1
    )
);

$obj2 = array();

foreach($obj as $v)
{
    if($v->qty > 1)
    {
        while($v->qty > 0)
        {
            $obj2[] = (object) array('id'=>$v->id, 'qty'=>1);
            --$v->qty;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $obj2[] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($obj2);
```

Comment: I admittedly like this answer better than my own  :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each row of your original array, and then for each count of the quantity, push an entry onto a new array with the id of the current row.

```
// SETTING UP INITIAL DATA FOR EXAMPLE
$object1 = new StdClass();
$object2 = new StdClass();

$object1->id = 1;
$object1->qty = 2;

$object2->id = 2;
$object2->qty = 1;

$array = array(
    $object1,
    $object2
);
// END SETTING UP INITIAL DATA

$array2 = array();

foreach($array as $row)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $row->qty; $i++)
    {
        $stdClass = new StdClass();
        $stdClass->id = $row->id;
        $stdClass->qty = 1;
        $array2[] = $stdClass;
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8b12544ebcb5cf41259e5edd610a325ee78f8b8)